# Use an external Link as the WordPress profile picture

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to write a Single Sign On (SSO) plugin for WordPress. I want to use an external image link as user's profile picture after user login. 
This image has a link which is located in http://www.example.com/image.png.

How can I do this in WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

Please add this code to your activated theme's functions.php file.

```
add_filter( 'author_link', 'modify_author_link', 10, 1 );        
function modify_author_link( $link ) {       
    $link = 'http://google.com/';
    return $link;                
}
```

You can use your any link, just change https://google.com to your link.
Thanks.

Comment: This is not a good practice, please follow the WordPress codex.

Comment: It's just a reference, Later we can change it with any links by getting current user and it's meta field or something.

Answer (score 0):

These Hooks ('get_avatar', 'avatar_defaults') are also available by WordPress, as an example:
you can check the documentation here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_avatar

````
function my_custom_avatar($avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt)
{
 echo $avatar . ' -> ' . $id_or_email .  ' -> ' . $size .  ' -> ' . $default .  ' -> ' .$alt;
 $avatar = 'https://www.example.com/yourImage';
 $avatar = "<img alt='{$alt}' src='{$avatar}' class='avatar avatar-{$size} photo' height='{$size}' width='{$size}' />";
 return $avatar;
}

add_filter( 'get_avatar', 'my_custom_avatar', 10, 5 );

add_filter( 'avatar_defaults', 'my_custom_avatar', 10, 1 );```
````